# 404 Not found - when I try to access the url for a Spring and Hibernate application (Rest Service based without front-end)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, http-status-code-404

everyone.
I am trying to create a Spring application, using Hibernate. 
The application have not been created with front-end part, only the entities, services, dao and rest controllers. 
When I run the application (I am using Eclipse as IDE and WebSphere - I need to use this configuration) and try to access the URL of the app, I receive 404 Not found.
 I also ran the application into debug mode with a breakpoint before the returning ResponseEntity of the request and with a print statement for the entity that I am trying to access (a user, for example). Whenever I do this, I try to access the URL, I receive in console application the message that I wanted to print and the entity from the DB. Also, every layer of the application is created in a Maven module.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
This is my UserController class:

```
import x.stm.entity.User;
import x.stm.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

 /*---Add new user---*/

@RequestMapping(path={"/user"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody User user) {
   userService.addUser(user);
      return ResponseEntity.ok().body("User was added" );
   }

  // ---Get a user by id---
@RequestMapping(path={"/user/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<User> get(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
      User user = userService.getUserById(id);
     System.out.println(user);
      return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
   }
```

}
 And this is application configuration and initializer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "x.stm.rs.controller" })
 public class RestApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

//
```

}

```
 public class RestApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] {HibernateConfig.class};
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { RestApplicationConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

Comment: How is the URL you try to connect to? Is the application running as a Root Application in WebSphere or using a context path?

Comment: the URL is something like this: http://localhost:9082/stm-eba-RS/user/1